# System.Data.SQLite - How to Create latest SQLite Version

Tags: .net, sqlite, version, system.data.sqlite

In Short my SQLite Databases are being created as version 3.24.0 however I am wanting SQLite Database version 3.25.0.

I need my .NET Application to create SQLite Databases using SQLite DB version 3.25 but so far I've been unable to do so.

I am looking to try out the new-ish Window Functions that are available with SQLite 3.25.

[SQLite Release 3.25](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_25_0.html)

Using the built in SQLite function `select sqlite_version();` I found that the SQLite databases that were being created by my .net application that uses the System.Data.SQLite package were being created as SQLite version 3.24.0.  I discovered this was due to my using an outdated version of the System.Data.SQLite version 1.0.109.0 released August 15, 2018.

[System.Data.SQLite Releases](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki)

I just updated my Nuget package from the **1.0.109.0** to the **1.0.110.0** that was only just released four days ago on March 4, 2019.

Now that I have the latest **1.0.110.0** version I ran my application which it then created the SQLite Databases it needs however when I checked the SQLite version they still say version **3.24.0** and I am still unable to utilize the new Window functions.

Any ideas as to how to force the creation of the SQLite Database using a specific version or at least the latest version?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the latest Nuget package 1.0.112 from October 2019. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Did you run the select sqlite_version(); command from within your application, or did you use a third-party database browser? In my situation, I was using SQLiteStudio to run the query, where it returned 3.24.   But when I ran the command from within my app, the correct version (3.30.1) was returned.

Comment: I never found a solution and was forced to move on to my other projects. 
 Regarding your question about SQLiteStudio that's exactly what I did 
 however I knew I wasn't using an updated version of the database due to my still not being able to utilize some of the newer windowing functions.  I never ran the check from within my app.  The lack of not having access to the newer functions showed I didn't have the latest version.

Comment: Your database could be created as a newer (3.30) SQLite version but if a 3rd party app is based on an older version, it will operate as such and prevent window functions from running. You have to run a query from your own app to be sure. I posted an answer here, maybe it will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60998314/6079533