# Using SQLite window functions and creating up-to-date SQLite version database

Tags: sqlite, function, version, lag

I'm unable to utilize SQLite window functions (e.g. LAG, LEAD). After some investigation it seems that this is due to the fact that SQLite database version is below 3.25.0, after which window functions were made available.

[Database created using SQLite 3.30.1 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD0Zj.png)
[image: database creation]

[However version 3.24.0 version displayed on this 'test' database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWBVT.png)
[image: different version dispalyed]

When queries which include window functions are tested, such as the ones provided on [sqlitetutorial site](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-lag/): [the following errors are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icWAq.png)
[image]

Could you please advise how to resolve this. I would much appreciate your support on this.

`SELECT CustomerId, Year, Total,
LAG (Total, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Year) PreviousYearTotal 
FROM CustomerInvoices 
WHERE CustomerId = 4;`

Comment: Upgrade the version of sqlite you're using with whatever that gui program is.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue. It looks like you're using SQLiteStudio, the latest version is 3.21 from December 2019. While your database was made in SQLite 3.30 (and your software is probably using 3.30), the version of SQLiteStudio you are using is based on 3.24.

There is an [outstanding feature request](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/issues/3471) to implement window functions in SQLiteStudio.  Until then, the best you can do is replace the sqlite3.dll in the SQLiteStudio program directory with a newer version (3.30 , 32-bit works).   Window functions will show as a syntax error, but the queries will still execute.